# Как добавлять товар в корзину на странице всех товаров?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как можно добавить товар в корзину на кастомной странице? Шорткоды не срабатывают, мой код тоже не хочет работать? Я так понимаю что это нужно делать Ajax запросами, но не совсем понимаю как, подскажите пожалуйста

```
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="product-main">
            <div class="product-img"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="avatar"><img class="responsive-img" src="<?php
            $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
            echo $thumb_url[0];
            ?>" alt=""></a>
            <div class="product-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
            <div class="product-size">Размер: <?php echo $product->get_attribute('size'); ?> см.</div>
            <div class="product-price__box">
                <div class="product-price">Цена: <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> грн.</div>
                <div class="info-cart"><a href="<?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?>"><img src="/wp-content/themes/dropship/assets/img/cart.png"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-button">
                <button class="fast-buy">Быстрая покупка</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Немного изменил свой код, теперь товары добавляются но по несколько штук, как это исправить?

```
<?php
 global $post, $woocommerce;
?>

    <div class="products-main">
        <?php  $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',  // указываем, что выводить нужно именно товары
        'posts_per_page' => 12, // количество товаров для отображения
        'orderby' => 'date', // тип сортировки (в данном случае по дате)
        'product_cat' => $sort,
        )); 



        while ( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="product-main">
            <div class="product-img"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="avatar"><img class="responsive-img" src="<?php
            $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
            echo $thumb_url[0];
            ?>" alt=""></a>
            <div class="product-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
            <div class="product-size">Размер: <?php echo $product->get_attribute('size'); ?> см.</div>
            <div class="product-price__box">
                <div class="product-price">Цена: <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> грн.</div>
                <div class="info-cart"><a href="<?php $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $thumb_id-1,1 ); ?>"><img src="/wp-content/themes/dropship/assets/img/cart.png"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-button">
                <button class="fast-buy">Быстрая покупка</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Какая такая "кастомная страница товара"? Такого в принципе быть не может. Для чего? Какая Цель?  Если тебе надо отдельный шаблон для неё - это другой вопрос. См документацию по шаблонам.

Comment: @SeVlad, у меня есть вывод всех товаров через цикл, мне нужно добавить к ним кнопку добавления товара в корзину, но у меня добавляется сразу несколько товаров, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавлять товар через ссылку ?add-to-cart=product_id